# Five Unique Individuals

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Each of the sections below has a single answer, and the five sections are related.  After finding the solution to one section, the others should be much easier.

> #### *The Best Friend*
>
> Whenever you're down and out, I'm in there like a dirty shirt.
>   Your other friends and I are gems.
>   When you renovated your bathroom, you needed me in order to work hard.

> #### *The Counsellor*
>
> If you're angry, I will come and provide some help.
>   If you're still angry, I will let you be, to help you evaluate.
>   I'll be with you in all your despair and anguish.

> #### *The Rabble-Rouser*
>
> If you're waiting on too many things, you can bring me in to shake things up.
>   If anyone is being ruthless or unforgiving, I'm in!
>   It is probably wise to remove me from employment.

> #### *The Party Animal*
>
> When I get together with any girl, there's bound to be a party.
>   In fact, no adequate party happens without me being there.
>   I cause a commotion at any party just by showing up.

> #### *The Efficiency Expert*
>
> Any young man can make use of me to get ahead.
>   Stick me on a letter, and it will arrive much faster.
>   If you were thinking of leaving your job and you brought me in to consult, I would advise not saying anything.

***To what does each of these sections refer?  What is the common bond between them all?***

Answer (score 29, accepted):

These individuals are

> the five vowels.

**The Best Friend**

> This is O.

Whenever you're down and out, I'm in there like a dirty shirt.

> O is in both "down" and "out".

Your other friends and I are gems.

> Adding O to "pals" gives "opals".

When you renovated your bathroom, you needed me in order to work hard.

> Adding O to "tiled" gives "toiled".

**The Counsellor**

> This is I.

If you're angry, I will come and provide some help.

> Adding I to "mad" gives "maid".

If you're still angry, I will let you be, to help you evaluate.

> Taking I away from "irate" gives "rate".

I'll be with you in all your despair and anguish.

> I is in "despair" and "anguish".

**The Rabble-Rouser**

> This is U.

If you're waiting on too many things, you can bring me in to shake things up.

> Adding U to "pend" gives "upend".

If anyone is being ruthless or unforgiving, I'm in!

> U is in "ruthless" and "unforgiving".

It is probably wise to remove me from employment.

> Removing U from "usage" gives "sage".

**The Party Animal**

> This is A.

When I get together with any girl, there's bound to be a party.

> Adding A to "gal" gives "gala".

In fact, no adequate party happens without me being there.

> A is in "adequate" and "party".

I cause a commotion at any party just by showing up.

> Adding A to "do" gives "ado".

**The Efficiency Expert**

> This is E.

Any young man can make use of me to get ahead.

> Adding E to "lad" gives "lead".

Stick me on a letter, and it will arrive much faster.

> Adding E to "mail" gives "email".

If you were thinking of leaving your job and you brought me in to consult, I would advise not saying anything.

> Adding E to "quit" gives "quiet".

Comment: "When I get together with any girl, there's bound to be a party." could be: gal -> gala

Comment: You've got it! If you can fill in the last few clues, I'll give you the check mark.

Comment: "If you're waiting on too many things, you can bring me in to shake things up." - this doesn't *exactly* fit but possibly "pending"/"upending"?

Comment: @question_asker  Yes. I was thinking just "pend" and "upend" but either works. Not the strongest clue, I'll admit. It was tougher finding things for U.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I only phrased it that way because I wasn't sure if there was something that fit better. Cool puzzle, thank you!

Comment: Well done! I was so close to finding "mail" -> "email" now that I think back to my attempt! That might've given me the breakthrough to find some of the other ones. Nice riddle. :)

Comment: This.Was.Brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a guess:

> Hand

The Best Friend

> The thumb, helps you get a grip on things

The Counsellor

> The pointer finger will guide you

The Rabble-Rouser

> Middle finger, used to flip people off

The Party Animal

> Ring finger, since getting engaged/married seems to start parties

The Efficiency Expert

> Pinky finger? Not quite sure how this would work, but pinky promises could help you getting ahead

Comment: Good try, but way off.  As I mentioned to Slepz, note the [tag:wordplay] tag on the question.

Answer (score 1):

A (probably wrong) guess:

> Mind altering substances

The best friend:

> Coffee is ubiquitous and helps you work

The counsellor:

> Cigarettes bring you back to even and force you to take time for reflection

The rabble-rouser:

> Cocaine should not be used at work and encourages brash behaviour

The party animal:

> Liquor is at parties and causes a commotion

The efficiency expert:

> Adderal (speed) young men use it a lot for studying, speed is fast, if you use it at work don't tell people

Comment: Good attempt, but unfortunately not even close.  :)   (Note the [tag:wordplay] tag on the question.)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is

> parts of a car

**The Best Friend**

Whenever you're down and out, I'm in there like a dirty shirt.

Your other friends and I are gems.

When you renovated your bathroom, you needed me in order to work hard.

> this refer to **TIRES**. When you are not using the car, it is just sitting ther. Other friends are the four tires and it works together. For the renovation, you need to be TIREless.

**The Counsellor**

If you're angry, I will come and provide some help.

If you're still angry, I will let you be, to help you evaluate.

I'll be with you in all your despair and anguish.

> my guess here is the **GAUGE**. This is use to provide info and help and also lets you evaluate your car.

**The Rabble-Rouser**

If you're waiting on too many things, you can bring me in to shake things up.

If anyone is being ruthless or unforgiving, I'm in!

It is probably wise to remove me from employment.

> This is the **BRAKE**. If you are waiting, you need some break. Also for unforgiving, like a fight, you need a break. Removing break from employment (I guess over breaks) is good.

**The Party Animal**

When I get together with any girl, there's bound to be a party.

In fact, no adequate party happens without me being there.

I cause a commotion at any party just by showing up.

> This one's funny. This is the **BUMPER**. Only for girls and it always comes in pairs. If this shows up in a party, it can cause commotion.

**The Efficiency Expert**

Any young man can make use of me to get ahead.

Stick me on a letter, and it will arrive much faster.

If you were thinking of leaving your job and you brought me in to consult, I would advise not saying anything.

> The last one is **SPOILER**. Getting ahead is getting spoiler information and it can arrive faster. About job, someone will not say anything so it would not spoil your plan or tell the plan as a spoiler.

Comment: Great attempt, but not it.